# Reduce artifacts when resampling a Brain MRI scan using scipy affine_transform

Tags: python, spatial-interpolation, scipy.ndimage

I have a [Brain MRI](https://github.com/rii-mango/Papaya/tree/master/tests/data/dicom). It is gray scale with 20 slices. I put it into a numpy array with shape (20,256,256).  I use `scipy.ndimage` [affine_transform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.affine_transform.html) to rotate and resample the array as below.

[image]

The dark stipes in the image is the artifact that I want reduce. The artifact is caused by the relatively large gap between the slices. In this example the pixel spacing is 0.85 mm, but the distance between slices is 7 mm.

I tried to change the order of the affine transform, but even order=5 has the same artifacts.  Below is order=0 (nearest neighbor)...

[image]

and you can see how the curvature of the skull is compounding the problem.  Are there any tricks to fix this?  Maybe I should add dummy data between the pixels to equalize the spacing? Maybe I should use polar coordinates to eliminate the curvature?  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The affine_transform using any order will look terrible. You need to do feature detection and delaunay triangulation on both images first, and then use the interpolating variable as a morph parameter to move the pixels between the corresponding features in adjacent images.  see link https://devendrapratapyadav.github.io/FaceMorphing/

see also this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5FEr5SiXB1g